# Insert Timestamp to .TXT file attachment from SP_Send_DBMail [SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a job that runs every monday that sends last weeks reports. I would like to have the attachment show either last weeks Week # ie. Week 36, Week 37 etc. or simply have the time stamp of when the report was sent, or when the file is opened to apply timestamp to report when user opens it.
Reason is that we have these reports posted and would like management to know if reports are current (which they usually arent) this way we can crack the whip :)

Heres what ive got and I will also show what I am requesting

Code to send report---------------------------------------------------------

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'profile',
@recipients = '10@ten.com',
@subject = 'Weekly',
@query = N'EXEC PTW.dbo.SP_Weekly',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_width = 150,
@query_result_header= 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Weekly.txt',
@importance = 'High',
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@query_result_separator = '   ';
```

RESULTS OF ATTACHMENT------------------------------------------------------

```
ID      Codes   TimeSUM Units   UPH     Goal%   
--      -----   ------- -----   ---     -----   
3476    HS-HY   5:53    9520    1618    140%    
2377    HS-HY   13:37   21638   1589    138%    
2372090 HS-HY   4:20    6036    1393    121%    
43864   HS-HY   13:46   15035   1092    95% 

(4 rows affected)
```

What I would like to see is any of the below

```
WEEK_35 or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or Timestamp of when file is opened
ID      Codes   TimeSUM Units   UPH     Goal%   
--      -----   ------- -----   ---     -----   
3476    HS-HY   5:53    9520    1618    140%    
2377    HS-HY   13:37   21638   1589    138%    
2372090 HS-HY   4:20    6036    1393    121%    
43864   HS-HY   13:46   15035   1092    95% 

(4 rows affected)
```

I would prefer the most to show the week # but any would work
I have already coded the SP to where I insert last weeks dates in a column of the resultset but that is extremely ugly seeing the date as many times as there are row, and for the sake of saving space I only showed 4 rows. Any ideas or help? I also have tried to have the recipients simply press`F5` when they open the file to insert timestamp that way....Its easy to show a horse to water, but extremely difficult to make it drink :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Show the Sent Date, my idea is to change the subject and query_attachment_filename to reflect the current week, for example:

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(50)
SET @FileName = 'Weekly_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Datepart(Week, Getdate())) + '.txt'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'profile',
@recipients = '10@ten.com',
@subject = @FileName,
@query = N'EXEC PTW.dbo.SP_Weekly',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_width = 150,
@query_result_header= 1,
@query_attachment_filename = @FileName,
@importance = 'High',
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@query_result_separator = '   ';
```

Comment: Yea, this approach works best for what i need to acheive